# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '59:46.5' while reading timstamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have timestamp in my data of this format 59:46.5

My data looks like this
[image]
I am applying clustering techniques to detect outliers but I got errors

File "pandas_libs\lib.pyx", line 615, in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '59:46.5'

```
import pandas as pd# visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt# algorithm
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("D:/user/Iotdata/data.csv")
```

Comment: What's the output you expect when you do `df['phenomenon_time'].astype('datetime64').astype(int)`? What do you expect for example in the first cell, the one with `59:46.5`

Comment: You obviously can't convert `59:46.5` to an integer.  What is your actual question?

Comment: so how can i read this if I will simple read this by ("D:/user/Iotdata/data.csv")  i got same error ValueError: could not convert string to float: '59:46.5'

Comment: Why are you trying to call `.astype(int)` on a value that is clearly not an integer?

Comment: i saw one thread where there is proper timestamp 2020-02-01 19:00:00+00:00' they solved it like this that's why ..

Comment: how can read time coulmn in my data

Comment: `'59:46.5'` can't be cast to integer, neither to float, what about just using `datetime`?

Comment: i am already using DateTime see my question

Comment: it gibes this error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'